# Converting floats to NSData and back in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In an iphone application, I'm looking to convert a float to NSData for it to be sent over bluetooth and then converted back again when it's received. I have the bluetooth part working fine, but when I use this to convert to NSData:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]init];

float z = 9.8574; // Get the float value, 9.8574 is just an example

[data getBytes:&z length:sizeof(float)];
```

I can not convert it back to a float. I've tried a couple of methods but I'm wondering if this is the correct way to encode the float to NSData??

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to display your NSData at sender side and at receiver side?

Comment: How can I display it, feed it into a NSString??

Comment: Your friend here is a hex dump tool. Either write one yourself or use `NSLog()` to print the NSData out to the console. It will print it in hex.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is how to encode and decode a `float` with `NSData`:

> **encoding:**

```
NSMutableData * data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
float z = ...;
[data appendBytes:&z length:sizeof(float)];
```

> **decoding:**

```
NSData * data = ...; // loaded from bluetooth
float z;
[data getBytes:&z length:sizeof(float)];
```

A couple of things to note here:

**1.** You have to use `NSMutableData` if you are going to add things to the data object after creating it. The other option is to simply load the data all in one shot:

`NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&z length:sizeof(float)];`

**2.** the `getBytes:length:` method is for *retrieving* bytes from an `NSData` object, not for copying bytes into it.

Comment: Just what I was after, looked like I was decoding when I thought I was encoding!!

Comment: That could cause some problems `:)`

Comment: Good answer! But shouldn't the conversion from bytes use the data size. So instead of sizeof(float) it would be [data getBytes:&z length:sizeof(data)];