# Mutable data to string to float - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

```
float serverTime = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] floatValue];

NSLog(@"String: %@ Float: %f", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], serverTime);
```

responseData is NSMutableData. Receiving data via NSURLConnection. This is returning:

```
2013-04-29 11:02:44.479 Time Test[7894:907] String: 1367247763.97 Float: 1367247744.000000
2013-04-29 11:02:44.996 Time Test[7894:907] String: 1367247764.41 Float: 1367247744.000000
2013-04-29 11:02:45.524 Time Test[7894:907] String: 1367247764.94 Float: 1367247744.000000
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and guess it is floating point precision

Comment: Try using a `double`, but eventually you will run into the same problem.  If you can get your responseData to be an integral type, that would be more accurate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precision of Floating Point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/precision-of-floating-point)

Comment: I think I'll try an integral type. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281607/converting-floats-to-nsdata-and-back-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use double instead of integer.